# filter and lambda: passing more than one argument?

Tags: python, lambda, filter, arguments

I try to print a list of number that are divisible by given number. However, the console said:

```
lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Code:

```
inp1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
inp2 = int(input("Enter a divisor: "))

result = list(filter(lambda x, inp2: x % inp2 == 0, range(inp2, inp1)))
print("Numbers divisible by", inp2, "are", result)
```

How should I fix this by keep using lambda and filter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Getting filter to work with lambda taking multiple arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391043/python-getting-filter-to-work-with-lambda-taking-multiple-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix in the case is to give the second argument a default value:

```
#inp1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
#inp2 = int(input("Enter a divisor: "))
inp1 = 42
inp2 = 6

result = list(filter(lambda x, inp2=inp2: x % inp2 == 0, range(inp2, inp1)))
print("Numbers divisible by", inp2, "are", result)
```

Output:

```
Numbers divisible by 6 are [6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36]
```

Comment: Why would giving it a default value be better than leaving it empty?

Comment: @Ludisposed: May not matter much and depends on what the OP wants. Leaving it out as you did would mean the value used will be whatever `inp2` happens to be when the `lambda` function is executed. Making it a default argument value will use  `inp2`'s value when the `lambda` is created (so wouldn't be affected by another value being assigned to `inp2` before it was run).

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `inp2` after the `lambda x` to make it working again.
The lambda was expecting the inp2 as an argument.

```
#inp1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
#inp2 = int(input("Enter a divisor: "))
inp1 = 10
inp2 = 2

result = list(filter(lambda x: x % inp2 == 0, range(inp2, inp1)))
print("Numbers divisible by", inp2, "are", result)
```

**output** **=** `Numbers divisible by 2 are [2, 4, 6, 8]`